# Python Pyglet slows down the animation. Objects are drawn slowly on the screen

Tags: python, animation, canvas, pyglet

I have repeatedly encountered the problem of slowing down animation when drawing various objects in Python. The problem is especially acute when the number of objects being drawn increases. I would not say that there are too many objects: *> = 200 (r=10) circles* are already a slide show.

I think it's not about the library I use ([pyglet](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet)). Before that I used the [p5py](https://github.com/p5py/p5) analog p5.js the brakes were even stronger (in truth, the creators of p5py know that it is much slower than its counterparts ([Issues from Github](https://github.com/p5py/p5/issues))). I also tried Tkinter - I thought that a clean canvas would solve my problems. But that didn't happen. And now I run the code in Pyglet - I get a slideshow.

I also noticed that the computer starts to take off on the jet thrust of coolers when the animation is slowing down. At the same time, the CPU load of the Python process never exceeds 20% (very strange). Computer not quite a calculator: *Intel i5-8300H 4 cores (8 virtual) 2.30 GHz*.

What could be the problem? An animation of 1000 points should not turn into a slideshow, even if it is Python.

PS. I also think that the problem is not in my code. Exactly the [same](https://github.com/belo4ya/Python-practice/tree/main/some_graphics/Star_field) (not about the code below) code on p5.js gives smooth animation in the browser (but the browser uses a video card). But just in case, I put my last count on Pyglet - this is not the top of optimization, but it should not work so slowly:

sketch.py

```python
import pyglet
import random
from firework import Firework


window = pyglet.window.Window(400, 400)
main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

fireworks = [Firework(main_batch)]


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main_batch.draw()


def update(dt):
    if random.random() < 0.03:
        fireworks.append(Firework(main_batch))

    for f in fireworks:
        f.update()
        if f.done():
            fireworks.remove(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1 / 120.0)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

particle.py

```python
import p5
import pyglet


class Particle(pyglet.shapes.Circle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, firework, batch=None):
        radius = 2
        if firework:
            radius = 4
        super().__init__(x, y, radius, radius * 5, color, batch)

        self.color = color
        self.firework = firework
        self.opacity = 255
        self._done = False

        self.acc = p5.Vector(0, 0)
        if self.firework:
            self.vel = p5.Vector(0, p5.random_uniform(8, 12))
        else:
            self.vel = p5.Vector.random_2D() * p5.random_uniform(-10, -2)

    @property
    def batch(self):
        return self._batch

    def update(self):
        self.acc += p5.Vector(0, -0.2)

        if not self.firework:
            self.vel *= 0.9
            if self.opacity > 4:
                self.opacity -= 4
            else:
                self._done = True
                self.opacity = 0

        self.vel += self.acc
        pos = p5.Vector(self.x, self.y) + self.vel

        self.x = pos.x
        self.y = pos.y

        self.acc *= 0

    def done(self):
        return self._done
```

firework.py

```python
import p5
import random
from particle import Particle


class Firework:

    def __init__(self, batch):
        self.color = tuple(random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3))
        self.firework = Particle(p5.random_uniform(400), 0, self.color, True, batch=batch)
        self.bach = batch
        self._exploded = False
        self.particles = []

    def done(self):
        if self._exploded and len(self.particles) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def explode(self):
        for _ in range(70):
            p = Particle(self.firework.x, self.firework.y, self.color, False, batch=self.firework.batch)
            self.particles.append(p)

    def update(self):
        if not self._exploded:
            self.firework.update()

            if self.firework.vel.y < 0:
                self._exploded = True
                self.explode()
                self.firework.delete()

        for p in self.particles:
            p.update()

            if p.done():
                self.particles.remove(p)
                p.delete()
```

Comment: Have you considered that the 20% CPU usage may mean that it is only using a single CPU core? Python generally likes to run on a single thread. In that case, a single threaded application running on a processor with 4 cores would only ever be able to get up to about 25% CPU usage.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I didn't think about it. You are absolutely right. But still, does Canvas require even more resources for simple animation?